# wrong output in removing certain characters from a csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file (with `;` as the delimiter) in which there are certain characters present which I want to remove. A sample of my data is:

```
PREDNISOLONE ACETATE 100MG/ML INJ,SUSP [VA Product];PREDNISOLONE ACETATE 100MG/ML INJ,SUSP [VA Product]
ACETAMINOPHEN 160MG/5ML (ALC-F) SUSP [VA Product];ACETAMINOPHEN 160MG/5ML (ALC-F) SUSP [VA Product]
NITISINONE 2MG CAP [VA Product];NITISINONE 2MG CAP [VA Product]
TRIMETHAPHAN CAMSYLATE;TRIMETHAPHAN CAMSYLATE
CAFFEINE 100MG TAB [VA Product];CAFFEINE 100MG TAB [VA Product]
CASTOR OIL [VA Product];CASTOR OIL [VA Product]
```

As you can see there are `[]` or `()` present around some parts of the data and I want to remove them and all the data present between them. So in above example `[VA Product]` and `(ALC-F)` will get removed. I wrote this code but it is producing the wrong output:

```
input = open('input_file1.csv', 'r')
    lines = csv.reader(input)
    output = open('output_file1.csv', 'w')
    writer = csv.writer(output)

    conversion = '()[]{}'
    text = input.read()
    newtext = ''
    for c in text:
        newtext += '' if c in conversion else c
        writer.writerow(c)

    input.close()
    output.close()
```

What mistake I am making here and what is the correct way?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression on each of the column entries to remove the text between brackets. It also removes any double spaces from the resulting text:

```
import csv
import re

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=';')
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    for row in csv_input:
        csv_output.writerow([re.sub(r'([\(\[].*?[\)\]])', '', c).strip().replace('  ', ' ') for c in row])
```

This would result in a comma delimited `output.csv` files as follows:

```
"PREDNISOLONE ACETATE 100MG/ML INJ,SUSP","PREDNISOLONE ACETATE 100MG/ML INJ,SUSP"
ACETAMINOPHEN 160MG/5ML SUSP,ACETAMINOPHEN 160MG/5ML SUSP
NITISINONE 2MG CAP,NITISINONE 2MG CAP
TRIMETHAPHAN CAMSYLATE,TRIMETHAPHAN CAMSYLATE
CAFFEINE 100MG TAB,CAFFEINE 100MG TAB
CASTOR OIL,CASTOR OIL
```

Note: this does not match brackets, it assumes `[abc)` is not present. Also add `delmiter=';'` to the `csv.writer` if required.

---

To also remove everything after a first comma, the script could be adapted as follows:

```
import csv
import re

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=';')
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter=';')

    for row in csv_input:
        csv_output.writerow([re.sub(r'([\(\[].*?[\)\]])', '', c).strip().replace('  ', ' ').split(',', 1)[0] for c in row])
```

Giving:

```
PREDNISOLONE ACETATE 100MG/ML INJ;PREDNISOLONE ACETATE 100MG/ML INJ
ACETAMINOPHEN 160MG/5ML SUSP;ACETAMINOPHEN 160MG/5ML SUSP
NITISINONE 2MG CAP;NITISINONE 2MG CAP
TRIMETHAPHAN CAMSYLATE;TRIMETHAPHAN CAMSYLATE
CAFFEINE 100MG TAB;CAFFEINE 100MG TAB
CASTOR OIL;CASTOR OIL
```

Comment: Thanks this works! Just on a side note if from each field within a row of the csv I want to remove `, ` and everything that follows it within that field how can I do that? Like for `PREDNISOLONE ACETATE 100MG/ML INJ,SUSP [VA Product];PREDNISOLONE ACETATE 100MG/ML INJ,SUSP [VA Product]` make it `PREDNISOLONE ACETATE 100MG/ML INJ;PREDNISOLONE ACETATE 100MG/ML INJ`. Apologies if its a differnet question from my main post!

Comment: Nevermind I found the way for that. Using `split()`. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

`input.read()` reads in the entire contents of the file. Thus, your line `for c in text` is iterating over characters in the file, rather than in each line of the csv.

You made a csv reader called `lines` and then didn't use it at all, so start there. But also, you're not going to want `writer.writerow(c)`, since you don't want a new row for each character.

Again, you declared `newtext` and are building it up in a seemingly reasonable way, but then you don't use it – I think you want `writer.writerow(newtext)`, but note that you want it *outside* the loop.